# FQL Result Issue

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql, comments

In looking at the stream table, the documentation says ..

**updated_time  time**
The time the post was last updated, which occurs when a user comments on the post, expressed as a Unix timestamp

**created_time  time**
The time the post was published, expressed as a Unix timestamp

However, when I execute a FQL query against the table I see

<created_time>1328136721</created_time>
<updated_time>1328136721</updated_time>

even though 700+ comments have been made on the post.  Given the documentation, if a comment has been made on a post, I don't see how the 2 timestamps can ever be the same.

Comment: might be a bug.  Did you look thru the bug database at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs ?

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems the appear for status with 30+ comments, as per [this bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274107099276048).  It is currently marked "Assigned".